# Blueimp's Jquery Upload, process options on my files

Tags: javascript, jquery, file-upload, blueimp

Im using Blueimp's Jquery upload plugin to upload multiple files to my server with added info.

The stage is like this, I have and Add Files Button, and a Save to Server button, what im doing here is in the add callback im creating my table to display the files that im prepping to add. Im creating a hidden submit button  on each of the table rows and a Cancel button to remove file from queue.

When i hit my "Save to Server" button, it calls all the hidden "submits" button from the rows and its uploading great, so far so good.

Im having trouble processing options,

imageMaxWidth: 1500,
imageMaxHeight: 1200,
imageQuality: 0.8,
imageCrop: false

in other projects i have used :

```
                data.process(function () {
                    return $this.fileupload('process', data);
                }).done(function() {
                    data.submit();
                });
```

but thats not working here telling me $this is undefined, so i need help with this plz

here's my buttons code:

```
var cancel_btn = $('<button/>')
.addClass('btn btn-warning cancel pull-right')
.html('<i class="icon-ban-circle icon-white"></i><span> Cancel');

var upload_btn = $('<button/>')
    .addClass('btn btn-warning upload pull-right hidden')
    .html('<i class="icon-ban-circle icon-white"></i><span> Upload');

//this is my "Save to Server" button
$('.guardar').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.upload').click();
});
```

and here is my fileupload code:

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
    url: CI.base_url + 'admin/do_upload',
    dataType: 'json',
    disableImageResize:  /Android(?!.*Chrome)|Opera/
        .test(window.navigator.userAgent),
    imageMaxWidth: 1500,
    imageMaxHeight: 1200,
    imageQuality: 0.8,
    imageCrop: false,
    add: function (e, data) { 
        //Se checa si son imagenes
        var fileType = data.files[0].name.split('.').pop(), allowdtypes = 'jpeg,jpg,png,gif,JPEG,JPG,PNG,GIF';
             if (allowdtypes.indexOf(fileType) < 0) {
                alert('Solo puedes cargar imágenes .jpg, .png y .gif');
                goUpload = false;
                return false;
        }//Se termina de revisar si son imagenes

        //Se checa si el tamaño no excede de 3 MB
        if(data.files[0].size > 3300000){
            alert('La Imagen no puede pesar mas de 3MB.');
            goUpload = false;
            return false;
        }//Termina el chequeo si la imagen es de mas de 3MB o no

        $.each(data.files, function (index, file) {

            var tr = document.createElement('tr');
            data.context = $(tr);
            var td1 = document.createElement('td');
            var td2 = document.createElement('td');
            var td3 = document.createElement('td');
            var td4 = document.createElement('td');
            var td5 = document.createElement('td');
            var td6 = document.createElement('td');

            var img_src = '';
            img_src = URL.createObjectURL(data.files[0]);

            $(td1).append('<img class="imagen_preview" src="' + img_src + '"/>');
            $(td2).append(file.name);
            $(td3).append(file.size);
            $(td4).append(cancel_btn.clone(true).data(data));
            $(td5).append(upload_btn.clone(true).data(data));
            $(td6).append('<input type="text" name="precio" class="input_precio">');
            $(tr).append(td1,td2,td3,td4, td5, td6);
            $('#files_list tbody').append(tr);

            //Here i add the submit handler to each submit button
            $('.upload').eq(-1).on('click',function(e){//button to upload only this file
                  e.preventDefault();
                  //data.submit();

                  //this is the code thats not working, it doesnt process my options
                  data.process(function () {
                    //return $this.fileupload('process', data);
                  }).done(function() {
                    data.submit();
                  });
             });

            $('.cancel').on('click', function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                $(this).parent().parent().remove();
            })
        });
    },
    progressall: function (e, data) {
       var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
        $('.bar').show();
        $('#progress .bar').css(
            'width',
            progress + '%'
        ).text(progress);
    },
    submit: function(e, data){
        var input = data.context.find('.input_precio').val();
        data.formData = ({'costo': input});

    },
    done: function(e, data){
        console.log(data);
        var nombre_archivo = data.result.files[0].name;
        var nombre_coleccion = $('#nombre_coleccion').val();
        var pensamiento = $('#texto_pensamiento').val();
        var costo = data.formData.costo;
        var arreglo = {nombre: nombre_archivo, nombre_coleccion: nombre_coleccion, pensamiento: pensamiento, costo:costo};

        $.post(CI.base_url + 'admin/agregar_archivos', arreglo , function(success){
            //alert(success);
        });
    },
    stop: function(e){
        alert('se termino');
    }
});
```

some comments are in spanish, but i leave them like that cause i think they are irrelevant

I'll appreciate any help

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

$this doesn't exist...

```
// Put this just inside the add function, 1st line
var $this = $(this);
```

'this' is a reference to the HtmlInputFile DOM element when inside the scope of the add() function so the following should now work.

return $this.fileupload('process', data);

The fileupload() function exists on the jquery object for the HtmlInputFile control, the root cause of your problem is you have not accessed the jquery object.  You could access this again via the DOM so the following should also work.

```
return $('#fileupload').fileupload('process', data);
```

A tiny bit about the 'this' keyword:

The 'this' keyword is a reference to the callee of said function, as you have several functions within the add function each one will change the context of this when within the scope of the function.  I'd recommend further reading on the this keyword and scope in JavaScript, its fundamental to the language.

Beyond the scope of your question:

You may want to re-factor the code to remove the events from the constructor.  IMO this would make the code easier to manage and testable, perhaps something like this...

```
var _$uploadControl = $('#fileupload');

function _start() {
    var options;

    options = {
        url: '',
        dataType: '',
        etc...
    };

   _$uploadControl.fileupload(options);

   _$uploadWidget.on('fileuploadadd', function (e, data) { _fileAddedToUpload(data); });
   _$uploadWidget.on('fileuploadprogressall', function (e, data) { _filesUploadProgress(data);
}

function _fileAddedToUpload(data){
   // Add logic

  data.process(function () {
      return _$uploadControl.fileupload('process', data);
  }).done(function() {
      data.submit();
  });
}

function _filesUploadProgress(data){
    // Progress bar logic
}
```